# problemas json_encode

Tags: php, html, ajax, json

sera que alguien tiene los conocimientos sobre como se aplica json encode? realmente mi json sirve lo envio atravez de ajax y tanto envia y recibe datos sin problemas, mi unico problema es que quiero mostrar los datos que recibo en pantalla (manteniendolas en una variable php), pero cuando agrego codigo de mas va mal en mi php por ejemplo esto en mi php donde recibo los datos.

```
<?php   
$servicio=!empty($_POST['servicio']) ? $_POST['servicio'] : NULL;
$producto=!empty($_POST['producto']) ? $_POST['producto'] : NULL;
$estado=  !empty($_POST['estado'])   ? $_POST['estado']   : NULL;
?>
<?php 
 $data=array('servicio' => $servicio,
          'producto' => $producto,
          'estado' => $estado,
          'success'=>'Todo OK');
          echo json_encode($data); 
 ?>
```

hasta aquí va bien pero abajo de ese codigo php quiero agregar esto con el fin del cambiar el div por medio de la accion del ajax y que me muestre los valores actualizados en pantalla cada vez que aprete el boton que todo se controla atravez del ajax.  Esto lo pongo abajo del codigo anterior pero a la ora de depurar con el navegador me arroja error y si le quito este codigo vuelve todo a la normalidad, es como que si no me aceptara mas codigo menos codigo html que ya nada que ver con el envio de datos al ajax pero no entiendo muy bien que puedo hacer al respecto. alguien prodria ayudarme?

```
 <div class="lista-nuevo">
     <?php 
       echo $servicio;
       echo $producto;
       echo $estado;
       ?>
     </div>
```

con este codigo mando a actualizar en el ajax al div

```
$("#lista-nuevo").load(" #lista-nuevo");
```

Comment: No puedes hacerlo así. JSON es un formato estructurado. Si luego agregas otro contenido suelto (como la parte del `div`) el JSON que antes construiste sería inválido. Lo que tienes que hacer es, con la respuesta recibida (en JavaScript) leer el JSON y mostrar los datos (usando código JavaScript, no PHP). Las peticiones Ajax son de ida y vuelta, cuando el código regresa al cliente ya tienes ahí los datos, no tiene sentido querer volver al servidor para mostrar algo que ya tienes en el cliente. Es importante comprender eso.

Comment: Si vas a trabajar con load (que es como un sucedáneo de Ajax) puedes emitir código HTML desde el servidor. Pero en ese caso debes obviar la parte del `json_encode` y crear en el servidor el contenido HTML. Esto es menos recomendable porque transportarás más datos (JSON es más ligero) y controlar posibles errores será más complicado (en JSON puedes poner una clave `error` en los flujos donde haya algún error y preguntar en la respuesta si existe o no una clave error).. Me suena a que te había explicado eso en una respuesta.